# Getting application or object defined error using offset

Tags: vba, offset

I have written this example code to reporduce the error:

```
Sub test()

Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range

Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("C1:C3")

For Each cell In rng
    If cell.Value2 = cell.Offset(-1, 0).Value2 Then
    cell.Offset(1, 0) = "TRUE"
    End If
Next cell

End Sub
```

In the line `If cell.Value = cell.Offset(-1, 0).Value2` I get an `Application or Object defined error` but I have no idea why. Usually it should check for C1 if B1 has the same value. Maybe I am just blind. Could anyone tell me why this is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Offset`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840060.aspx) property of `Range` object has the order of arguments: `Offset(RowOffset, ColumnOffset)`, your code refers to the cells `C0`, which doesn't exist, try `Offset(0,-1)`.